# How do I prevent Nautilus from hiding some file extensions?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I've just installed the new version of Ubuntu (12.04) and nautilus seems to hide some file extension.

For example in my .local/application, the .desktop extension are not displayed. How to display the true name of files?

Comment: Do your `*.desktop` files have names starting with `.` (like `".foo.desktop"`)?

Comment: So you want to show the .desktop part of the Desktop files. Something like minecraft to minecraft.desktop (without hiding the .desktop part). If so then it is a good question.

Comment: I don't think any of the 3 current answers actually answer this question. nautilus is a file browser. It should be possible to see the actual names of the files it is browsing without having to change those files!

Answer (score 2):

Those are not hidden files, they are "desktop" files. I don't know to show real names of desktop files in a general manner but simply changing them to non-executable does what you want.

So to do this for each file, right click the file and follow the steps:

```
-> properties -> permissions -> Uncheck: Allow executing file as program
```

Via terminal:

```
chmod -x /where/is/this/desktop/file.desktop
```

**But, if you do so, you can not execute the application using this .desktop file.**

Comment: ahh, ok actually those icons in /usr/share/applications are .dektop converted in executables files, that's why we can't see the file name on nautilus and only its icons associated. You could see its real name by terminal `$ ls /usr/share/applications`

Comment: But why in ~/.local/share/applications do you can see those files like normal files even though they are .desktop files? , and they aren't displaying theirs icons there.

Comment: Ok, there if you double click any .desktop file you can select "Trust and Lauch" on the alert that is showed , now your .desktop file is showed as an icon.

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus considers all `.fileName` to be hidden files (files starting with a dot character). Hit `ctrl+h` as suggested to show these files.

Comment: But not all `.desktop` files have names starting with `.` -- and on my system, most of them don't.